# How to remove the first character from the join statement in where clause of the SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I want to remove the first character returning from the cvdl.C statement in the below SQL query and that value should be match up with the ccp.B value.

For an example if the real value return by the cvdl.C statement is 4500, I want to remove 4 and take only the 500 part to match with the value in the ccp.B value. Also I need to pass a input parameter value for the query.

How can I modify below SQL query to achieve this objective?

```
SELECT ccp.A
FROM ccp, cvdl
WHERE cvdl.J = 'Example' and ccp.B = cvdl.C
```

Comment: What if you have `450` or `45001` etc..? More sample data and a generic rule needed I think. Moreover, you can leave the old style join syntax, and use explicit join such like `SELECT ccp.A
FROM ccp JOIN cvdl ON ccp.B = cvdl.C` ( *Btw, I didn't downvote just commented* :) )

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan is right. Also what if the value is `14500` instead  `4500` ? Is the first character is always single digit ? you may provide sample randomized data similar to actual ones.

Comment: Do not bother about the values, I just wanted to query which work for this scenario generally. Also I forget to mention I need to pass a input parameter value as well. I will edit it.

Comment: What data type? In your example you use a number, but then the 4 from 4000 removed would end up 0. Is this what you want? Or are we talking about strings ('4000' becomes '000')?

Comment: BTW: Comma-separated joins (`FROM ccp, cvdl`) are a thing of the past. It is weird seeing you use them still. This looks like you learnt SQL thirty years ago and then stopped there. While Oracle was very late adopting the "new" syntax (`FROM ccp INNER JOIN cvdl ON ...`) in 2001, this is still 19 years ago.

Comment: Another side note: Why do you join at all when you only select from one table? Shouldn't you rather use `EXISTS` or `IN`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner actually its a string. Yeah would have better I have chosen a string to show the example. Anyway that's why I told not to worry about the value.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Actually it is not about joining only a one table. Since it would be complicated to write the post as well as understand to you all I decided to only write the post about what actually I want to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the ansi-syntax to join

```
    select ccp.A,
      from ccp
inner join cvdl on ccp.B = substr(cvdl.C, 2)
     where cvdl.J = 'Example'
```

Comment: I just modified the question where I also need to pass a input parameter value as an input as well. Do this work for this scenario as well. I did not get the correct response when I modified this to my scenario unfortunately.

Comment: I just checking why I did not get the desired result for some time. Finally I found we should give the substr 2nd parameter as 2 instead of 1 in order to remove the first character. Hope it is correct and mistake from you. Thanks very much for the solution.